# Matching Colors in Matlab Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I'm plotting six decaying functions along with the curves that envelope their amplitudes. How can I make it so the color of each envelope curve (A) matches the color of the decaying function (y) it is enveloping?

```
k = 1;
t = 0:0.1:10;

for R = 0:0.4:2;
    y = exp(-(R/2).*t).*sin(k.*t);
    A = exp(-(R/2).*t);
    hold on
    plot(t,y);
    hold on 
    plot(t,A);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the default color order then cycle through each one as you plot.  As longs as you don't exceed the max number of default colors which is 7.

```
k = 1;
t = 0:0.1:10;
defColors = get(0,'defaultAxesColorOrder');
j = 1;
for R = 0:0.4:2;
    y = exp(-(R/2).*t).*sin(k.*t);
    A = exp(-(R/2).*t);
    plot(t,y,'Color',defColors(j,:));
    hold on 
    plot(t,A,'Color',defColors(j,:));
    j = j+1;
end
```